# Any efficient way to create vocabulary of top frequent words from list of sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I figured out how to use tfidf schema to capture distribution of the words along the document. However, I want to create vocabulary of top frequent and least frequent words for list of sentences.

Here is some part of text preprocessing:

```
print(my.df) -> 
(17298, 2)

print(df.columns) ->
Index(['screen_name', 'text'], dtype='object')



txt = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]","",txt)
txt = re.sub(r"@([A-Z-a-z0-9_]+)", "", txt)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(txt)
token_lemmetized = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token).lower() for token in tokens]
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

then this is my second attempt:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

all_words = list(chain.from_iterable(df['text']))
for i in all_words:
    x=Counter(df['text'][i])
    res= [word for word, count in x.items() if count == 1]
    print(res)
```

in above approach I want to create most frequent and least frequent words from list of sentences, but my attempt didn't produce that outuput? what should I do? any elegant way to make this happen? any idea? can anyone give me possible idea to make this happen? Thanks

**example data snippets** :

here is data that I used and file can be found safely here: [example data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/2a7fa59bebdd3a9a0e05c6869e487dac)

**sample input  and output**:

inputList = {"RT @GOPconvention: #Oregon votes today. That means 62 days until the @GOPconvention!", "RT @DWStweets: The choice for 2016 is clear: We need another Democrat in the White House. #DemDebate #WeAreDemocrats ", "Trump's calling for trillion dollar tax cuts for Wall Street.", From Chatham Town Council to Congress, @RepRobertHurt has made a strong mark on his community. Proud of our work together on behalf of VA!}

**sample output of tokens**

```
['rt', 'gopconvention', 'oregon', 'vote', 'today', 'that', 'mean', '62', 'day', 'until', 'gopconvention', 'http', 't', 'co', 'ooh9fvb7qs']
```

**output**:

I want to create vocabulary for most frequent words and least frequent words from give data. any idea to get this done? Thanks

Comment: If you have lists of words, you can use `collections.Counter()` to get most and least common

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks, could you elaborate your full answer if it is possible?

Comment: First off, I apologize, it looks like you're already using Counter, though I don;t see the import. Instead of looping through your words and searching in the df column, you could just use `c=Counter(all_words)` and then access the methods in it with c.most_common()`. For more specific help, it would help to see a sample input and output in your question

Comment: @G.Anderson I updated my post, also you can safely browse example data snippet. Any concrete solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collections.Counter()` can do this for you.  I couldn't get to your data link, but copying and pasting the text you posted as an example, here's how it could be done:

```
>>> import collections
>>> s = "in above approach I want to create most frequent and least frequent 
words from list of sentences, but my attempt didn't produce that outuput?
what should I do? any elegant way to make this happen? any idea? can anyone 
give me possible idea to make this happen? Thanks"
>>> c = dict(collections.Counter(s.split()))
>>> c
{'in': 1, 'above': 1, 'approach': 1, 'I': 2, 'want': 1, 'to': 3, 'create': 1, 
'most': 1, 'frequent': 2, 'and': 1, 'least': 1, 'words': 1, 'from': 1,
 'list': 1, 'of': 1, 'sentences,': 1, 'but': 1, 'my': 1, 'attempt': 1, 
 "didn't": 1, 'produce': 1, 'that': 1, 'outuput?': 1, 'what': 1, 'should': 1, 
 'do?': 1, 'any': 2, 'elegant': 1, 'way': 1, 'make': 2, 'this': 2, 'happen?': 
2, 'idea?': 1, 'can': 1, 'anyone': 1, 'give': 1, 'me': 1, 'possible': 1, 
'idea': 1, 'Thanks': 1}
>>> maxval = max(c.values())
>>> print([word for word in c if c[word] == maxval])
['to']
```

You'll want to strip out punctuation marks and the like first; otherwise `happen` and `happen?` for example get counted as two different words.  But you'll notice that `c` here is a dictionary where the keys are words and the values are how many times the word shows up in the string.

**EDIT:** Here's something that will work across a list of multiple Tweets like you have.  You can use a regular expression to first simplify each Tweet to all lower-case, no punctuation marks, etc.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

fakenews = ["RT @GOPconvention: #Oregon votes today. That means 62 days until the @GOPconvention!",
            "RT @DWStweets: The choice for 2016 is clear: We need another Democrat in the White House. #DemDebate #WeAreDemocrats ",
            "Trump's calling for trillion dollar tax cuts for Wall Street.",
            "From Chatham Town Council to Congress, @RepRobertHurt has made a strong mark on his community. Proud of our work together on behalf of VA!"]

big_dict = {}

for tweet in fakenews:
    # Strip out any non-alphanumeric, non-whitespaces
    pattern = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+')
    tweet_simplified = pattern.sub('', tweet).lower()

    # Get the word count for this Tweet, then add it to the main dictionary
    word_count = dict(Counter(tweet_simplified.split()))
    for word in word_count:
        if word in big_dict:
            big_dict[word] += word_count[word]
        else:
            big_dict[word] = word_count[word]

# Start with the most frequently used words, and count down.
maxval = max(big_dict.values())
print("Word frequency:")
for i in range(maxval,0,-1):
    words = [w for w in big_dict if big_dict[w] == i]
    print("%d - %s" % (i, ', '.join(words)))
```

Output:

```
Word frequency:
3 - the, for
2 - rt, gopconvention, on, of
1 - oregon, votes, today, that, means, 62, days, until, dwstweets, choice, 2016, is, clear, we, need, another, democrat, in, white, house, demdebate, wearedemocrats, trumps, calling, trillion, dollar, tax, cuts, wall, street, from, chatham, town, council, to, congress, reproberthurt, has, made, a, strong, mark, his, community, proud, our, work, together, behalf, va
```

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't access your link.

Comment: can you try this gist: [data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/2a7fa59bebdd3a9a0e05c6869e487dac) ? how can I pick up the words that occured once or twice instead? Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry I have this error, `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'` when I continue with tokenized and lemmatized the fakenews tweets (like what I did in my post), how your solution works for tokens in nested list? could you point me out based on my intial attempt? because my input is list of tokens. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: "split" only works on strings, so make sure everything in your original list is actually a string.  If not add a command like `tweet = str(tweet)` right inside the `for` loop before you start using it. And like all lists in Python, your list of Tweet texts should be enclosed in a pair brackets, not braces. Braces are used for Python dictionaries and sets, not for lists.